# Exception handling in Celery?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, celery

I have a group of tasks each of which make a request to a standard oauth API endpoint, and are dependent on a **bearer_token**. The tasks will raise an exception during response processing if the **bearer_token** is expired.  There is also a `refresh_bearer_token` task, which handles updating the token once it expires.

Here is a pseudo-code for that:

```
from proj.celery import app

bearer_token = '1234'

class OauthError(Exception):
    pass

@app.task
def api_request():
    response = request(bearer_token, ...)
    if response.bearer_token_expired:
        raise OauthError('oauth')

@app.task
def refresh_bearer_token():
    ...
```

How can I schedule the `refresh_bearer_token` task to execute whenever an `OauthError` is raised?

The only solution I can find is using the `link_error` kwarg like this:

```
@app.task
def error_callback(uuid):
    exception_msg = AsyncResult(uuid).get(propagate=False, disable_sync_subtasks=False)
    if exception_msg = 'oauth':
        refresh_bearer_token.delay()
    else:
        raise 

api_request.apply_async(link_error=error_callback.s())
```

But this seems sub-optimal for several reasons, most notably because it spawns a synchronous child task within another synchronous child task, which [strongly discourged](http://docs.celeryq.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html?highlight=subtask#avoid-launching-synchronous-subtasks) in the docs.

> **Is there a more *pythonic* way of exception catching in celery?**

For example:

```
def catch(func_that_requires_oauth):
    try:
        func_that_requires_oauth.delay()
    except OauthError:
        refresh_bearer_token.delay() | func_that_requires_oauth.delay()
```

Comment: How many workers do you have, will they all start kicking off `refresh_bearer_token` tasks when it expires?

Comment: @IainShelvington for the sake of the example lets say I have several workers.  That is a good point that I wasn't considering, because in my example they would execute several `refresh_bearer_token` calls, but shouldn't.

Comment: This is a bit out of scope for this question, but I also have to consider how many clients (1 bearer_token per client) I have in a given queue.

Comment: Are there multiple different tasks that all require this oauth token?

Comment: @IainShelvington yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just throwing some ideas out there. You could create a base task that waits or retries if a lock has been acquired by the refresh_bearer_token task whenever it's called. When it fails it kicks off the refresh_bearer_token task and also retires itself.

A retry puts a copy of the running task to the back of the queue

Now you would have to implement some kind of locking, if the lock is already acquired the refresh_bearer_token just does nothing as another task should be updating it. You would need to add a TTL to this "lock" too to prevent some conditions when the `refresh_bearer_token` task fails

```
@app.task
def refresh_bearer_token():
    try:
        with aquire_lock(timeout=0):
            refresh_token()
    except TimeoutError:
        pass


class RequiresOauthTask(app.Task):
    abstract = True

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if lock_is_present():
            self.retry()  # or wait?
        return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)

    def on_failure(self, exc, task_id, args, kwargs, einfo):
        if isinstance(exc, OauthError):
            refresh_bearer_token.delay()
            self.retry()
        super().on_failure(exc, task_id, args, kwargs, einfo)


@app.task(base=RequiresOauthTask)
def my_task():
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks!  Classic case of the [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) I think.